# Macro to sum values from another Workbook with Multiple Sheets

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I am working on a project that requires me to sum multiple values in another excel workbook.

The other Workbook contains, say, 120 sheets. I want to take a certain value from each sheet, and sum it along with the rest. The cell reference for all the 120 values is fixed, for example J3.

Another thing worth mentioning (maybe) is that the sheet code names aren't organized (i.e. Sheet 1 all the way to Sheet 120), there have been several sheets added/removed in between.

Right now I'm getting

> Run Time Error 424 Object Required

```
Sub SumProject1P()
    Dim Project1P As Workbook
    Dim reserves
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim V As Variant

    Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open("FILE PATH")
    WS_Count = Workbook.Worksheets.Count
    V = Workbook.Worksheets
    reserves = sumrange(Workbook.Worksheets(V).range(Cells(1, 8)))
End Sub


Function sumrange(range)
    summ = 0
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        summ = summ + reserves
    Next
    reserves = summ
End Function
```

I hope to receive feedback and input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
Sub SumProject1P()

Dim Project1P As Workbook
Dim reserves As Long
Dim WS_Count As Integer
Dim filePath As String

    filePath = "Enter you file path"

    Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
    WS_Count = Project1P.Worksheets.Count


   For i = 1 To WS_Count
    If Sheets(i).range("J3") <> "" And IsNumeric(Sheets(i).range("J3")) Then
        reserves = reserves + Sheets(i).range("J3")
    End If
   Next

   MsgBox "Total of all sheets :" & reserves
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Santosh!  It did gave me an output but the result is wrong. It gave me a 575 but I'm expecting a 578.

Comment: In that case, Cells J3 may have numbers stored as text, fix & try again.

Comment: Thank you Santosh for your patience and help! I set the cell from "General" to "Number" across all the worksheets. yet the answer is still incorrect. Do you think it has to do with the sheet number issue I mentioned in the post?

Comment: I don't think so it is happening because of sheet number issue. Are there any hidden sheets?

Comment: Ok it worked after I declared reserves as Variant. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the `object required` error because you are not using the `Worsheets.count` function to any object.

**Your code:**

```
Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open("FILE PATH")
    WS_Count = Workbook.Worksheets.Count
```

You need to use this function for `Project1P` object.

```
 Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open("FILE PATH")
    WS_Count = Project1P .Worksheets.Count
```

Santosh already gave you the simplest way. Still if you want to do it by using `Function` then try the below.

```
Sub Sum()

Dim Project1P As Workbook
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim V As Variant
    Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open("File path")
    WS_Count = Project1P.Worksheets.Count
    sumrange (WS_Count)

End Sub

Function sumrange(TotalSheets As Integer)

     Dim reserves As Integer

     For i = 1 To TotalSheets
         If Sheets(i).range("J3") <> "" And IsNumeric(Sheets(i).range("J3")) Then
             reserves = reserves + Sheets(i).range("J3")
        End If
     Next

    MsgBox "Total of all sheets :" & reserves

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you Nandan A!