# How to sum a range of values from multiple worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I want to sum the same range of values (say B3:B292) in 120 worksheets such that:  ΣB3, ΣB4, ΣB5 ...... ΣB292.

I am not getting an error for the below VBA code, but it's also not returning any values.

```
 Sub FAggreg1PNFAWO()

 Dim Aggreg1PNFAWO As Workbook
 Dim WS_Count As Integer
 Dim filePath As String
 Dim i As Integer
 Dim TotalNp As Variant

 filePath = "Directory"

 Set Aggreg1PNFAWO = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
 WS_Count = Aggreg1PNFAWO.Worksheets.Count


For i = 1 To WS_Count
'Sheets(i).range("B3:B292") <> "" And
If IsNumeric(Sheets(i).range("B3:B292")) Then
    TotalNp = TotalNp + Sheets(i).range("B3:B292")
End If
Next
ActiveWorkbook.Close
ThisWorkbook.Activate
ActiveSheet.range("T4:T293").Value = TotalNp

End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't asked for a value. Your code checks if your range `IsNumeric` (I suspect that this is always returning FALSE and so your total will always be "" (as you've declared `TotalNp` as a Variant). So you are not getting anything returned. Are your columns in this range set as Text?

Comment: @pnuts I'm new to VBA, unfortunately I don't know what that is.

Comment: you should have been asked this in yesterdays question. Don't created duplicate questions.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51379712/macro-to-sum-values-from-another-workbook-with-multiple-sheets/51380681#51380681

Comment: @Zac The range is set as Numbers. Is it fine if I remove the condition and just keep the sum equation?

Comment: @NandanA This is for a different purpose, and in this case I'm summing a range rather than a single cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case try this:

```
Sub FAggreg1PNFAWO()
Dim Aggreg1PNFAWO As Workbook, myWB As Workbook
Dim WS_Count As Integer, i As Integer
Dim filePath As String
Dim TotalNp As Variant

Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook
filePath = "Directory"

Set Aggreg1PNFAWO = Workbooks.Open(filePath, ReadOnly:=True)
WS_Count = Aggreg1PNFAWO.Worksheets.Count

For X = 3 To 292
    For i = 1 To WS_Count
        If IsNumeric(Sheets(i).Range("B" & X)) Then
           TotalNp = TotalNp + Sheets(i).Range("B" & X).Value
        End If
    Next
    myWB.Activate
    myWB.ActiveSheet.Range("T" & i + 1).Value = TotalNp
    TotalNp = 0
    Aggreg1PNFAWO.Activate
Next X

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! 
It returned the same value for each cell in the output column. I think my logic in this code isn't right. I want to sum all B3 values across 120 sheets, and then do that for the entire column.

Comment: In that case the update I just made to the code should work.  I thought you were trying to sum the whole range not row by row

Comment: Many thanks. I think in the last part you meant ("T" & X + 1)? I put that and it's working perfectly. Thanks again @vba_sql_programmer

Comment: @Lavender_Lady haha yeah that was it.  If it works don't forget to check the answer as working for you so that other people don't keep trying to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `SUM` function to do this. In the below answer am assuming `B293` cell as empty and using it for summation. If you have some data in that cell then pick some other empty cell then try this.

```
Sub Sum()

Dim Project1P As Workbook
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim V As Variant

    Set Project1P = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Nandan\Desktop\SO\SO1.xlsx")
    WS_Count = Project1P.Worksheets.Count
    sumrange (WS_Count)

End Sub

Function sumrange(TotalSheets As Integer)

     Dim reserves As Variant

     For i = 1 To TotalSheets
       Sheets(i).range("B" & 293).Formula = "=SUM(B3:B292)"
     Next

     For i = 1 To TotalSheets
      reserves = reserves + Sheets(i).range("B" & 293)
     Next

     For i = 1 To TotalSheets
      Sheets(i).range("B" & 293).Clear
     Next  

    MsgBox "Total of all sheets :" & reserves

End Function
```